# Why does my sign up form work in every browser except Firefox?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox

It's available here: http://syllableapp.com/test

Basically, in Safari, Chrome, Opera, Webkit Nightly, etc. the form works beautifully and exactly as intended. In Firefox though, on submit it just ... doesn't do anything. Why is this?

Here's my JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();

        var email = $.trim($('.email').val());
        var emailRegEx = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;

        if (email == "" || !emailRegEx.test(email)) {
            $(this).effect("shake", { times:2 }, 75);
        }
        else {
            var data = "email=" + email;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "register_email.php",
                data: data,
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data == 1) {
                        $('form').hide();
                        $('form').html("<p class='success'>You'll be notified! Welcome aboard.</p>");
                        $('form').fadeIn(300);
                    }
                    else {
                        $('form').hide();
                        $('form').html("<p class='error'>Dang, there was an error. <a href='mailto:me@christianselig.com'>Email me?</a></p>");
                        $('form').fadeIn(300);
                    }
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
                    $('form').hide();
                    $('form').html("<p class='error'>Dang, there was an error. <a href='mailto:me@christianselig.com'>Email me?</a></p>");
                    $('form').fadeIn(300);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

And my PHP:

```
<?php
    $db = new mysqli("localhost", "swuclu_emailer", "etreadmill:(", "swuclu_syllable_emails");

    if ($db->connect_error) {
        echo "0";
    }
    else {
        $email = $_POST["email"];

        $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO emails (email) VALUES (?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
        $stmt->execute();

        echo 1;
    }
?>
```

What exactly is going on that every browser other than Firefox would work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your `scripts.js` file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
```

this should be

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="submit"]').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
```

otherwise event is undefined

Comment: Why does it work in the other browsers? Is it because Firefox chooses to die when asked to access a function on an undefined object, and the other browsers choose to quietly ignore it? Or it is related to scopes and closures, and the other browsers are able to find the `event` object?

Comment: you'd have to look at the source code of the browser for that. The right way to handle this would be to pause the script (the way Firefox does it).

Answer (score 5):

Enable the errors in the console to persist when the page changed.

You will see this error:

```
ReferenceError: event is not defined
http://syllableapp.com/test/scripts/scripts.js
Line 3
```

which takes you to the code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault(); //<--- here
```

looking at that, you see that event is not defined. Hence the error.

So add the variable event to the function argument list

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function(event) { //<-- added variable
```

Comment: When do I need to have event defined? Always?

Comment: you needn't add, unless you use it. it is useful if you want to prevent the default action from firing, for example, or to get some information from the event (what key was pressed etc)

Comment: bleh, you editted your answer to look pretty much the same as mine, even after I had posted exactly the same thing

Comment: @UkuLoskit I never looked at your answer... I posted the error and thought I would tell them how to fix it. Cry a river that you got the selected answer...